# Why is the inertia ellipsoid of a higher symmetry than the rigid body?

Tags: symmetry, geometry, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

I was always puzzled by this fact.

A uniform cube has a sphere-shaped inertia ellipsoid. The sphere has a higher symmetry then the cube.

Is there any deep reason or implication behind it?

Answer (score 6):

The inertia ellipsoid is computed from an integral about an axis - in other words you rotate the object. This will "smooth out" any symmetries and typically increase the symmetry.

Sorry this is a "early morning" intuitive explanation - maybe someone else will give you a more formal answer.

Comment: It is a good answer indeed.